# re.findall not returning full match?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a file that includes a bunch of strings like "size=XXX;". I am trying Python's `re` module for the first time and am a bit mystified by the following behavior: if I use a pipe for 'or' in a regular expression, I only see that bit of the match returned. E.g.:

```
>>> myfile = open('testfile.txt', 'r').read()
>>> re.findall('size=50;', myfile)
['size=50;', 'size=50;', 'size=50;', 'size=50;']

>>> re.findall('size=51;', myfile)
['size=51;', 'size=51;', 'size=51;']

>>> re.findall('size=(50|51);', myfile)
['51', '51', '51', '50', '50', '50', '50']

>>> re.findall(r'size=(50|51);', myfile)
['51', '51', '51', '50', '50', '50', '50']
```

The "size=" part of the match is gone (Yet it is certainly used in the search, otherwise there would be more results). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The problem you have is that if the regex that [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) tries to match captures groups (i.e. the portions of the regex that are enclosed in parentheses), then it is the groups that are returned, rather than the matched string.

One way to solve this issue is to use non-capturing groups (prefixed with `?:`).

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'size=50;size=51;'
>>> re.findall('size=(?:50|51);', s)
['size=50;', 'size=51;']
```

If the regex that `re.findall` tries to match does not capture anything, it returns the whole of the matched string.

Although using [character classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18425466/1907098) might be the simplest option in this particular case, non-capturing groups provide a more general solution.

Answer (score 16):

When a regular expression contains parentheses, they *capture* their contents to groups, changing the behaviour of `findall()` to only return those groups. Here's the relevant section from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> `(...)`
>
> > Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses,
> > and indicates the start and end of a group; the contents of a group
> > can be retrieved after a match has been performed, and can be matched
> > later in the string with the `\number` special sequence, described
> > below. To match the literals `'('` or `')'`, use `\(` or `\)`, or enclose them
> > inside a character class: `[(] [)]`.

To avoid this behaviour, you can use a *non-capturing* group:

```
>>> re.findall(r'size=(?:50|51);',myfile)
['size=51;', 'size=51;', 'size=51;', 'size=50;', 'size=50;', 'size=50;', 'size=50;']
```

Again, from the docs:

> `(?:...)`
>
> > A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.

Answer (score 5):

In some cases, the non-capturing group is not appropriate, for example with regex which detects repeated words (example from [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/regex.html#Grouping))

```
r'(\b\w+)\s+\1'
```

In this situation to get whole match one can use

```
[groups[0] for groups in re.findall(r'((\b\w+)\s+\2)', text)]
```

Note that `\1` has changed to `\2`.

Answer (score 3):

As others mentioned, the *"problem"* with [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) is that it returns a list of strings/tuples-of-strings depending on the use of capture groups. If you don't want to change the capture groups you're using (not to use character groups `[]` or non-capturing groups `(?:)`), you can use [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) instead of `findall`. This gives an *iterator* of ***`Match` objects***, instead of just strings. So now you can fetch the full match, even when using capture groups:

```py
import re

s = 'size=50;size=51;'
for m in re.finditer('size=(50|51);', s):
    print(m.group())
```

Will give:

```
size=50;
size=51;
```

And if you need a list, similar to `findall`, you can use a list-comprehension:

```
>>> [m.group() for m in re.finditer('size=(50|51);', s)]
['size=50;', 'size=51;']
```

Answer (score 2):

`'size=(50|51);'` means you are looking for `size=50` or `size=51` but only matching the `50` or `51` part (note the parentheses), therefore it does not return the `sign=`.

If you want the `sign=` returned, you can do:

```
re.findall('(size=50|size=51);',myfile)
```

Comment: `(...)` defines a match group. You could also use `(size=(50|51))` where you would have two match groups, the first being the full `size=5X` and the second being just the `5X` part.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is using `[]` instead of `()`. `[]` indicates a set of characters while `()` indicates a group match. Try something like this:

```
re.findall('size=5[01];', myfile)
```

Comment: helpful, though i am building up to more complicated regex where I will need ()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer), which also returns all matched values, in form of [Match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer:%7E:text=yielding%20Match%20objects) iterrator. It has method `.group()` that returns whole string.
So your code may looks next way

```py
myfile = open('testfile.txt', 'r').read()
matches = list(re.finditer('size=(50|51);', myfile))
matches[0].group() # size=50
```