# Python link scraper regex works when only searching for 1 extension type, but fails when matching more than one extension type

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

This is the test link I am using for this project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4cgwf2b6gk4bex4/AADtM1GDYgPDdv8QP6JdSOkba?dl=0

Now, the code below works when matching for .mp3 only (line 8), and outputs the plain link to a text file as asked.

```
import re
import requests

url = input('Enter URL: ')
html_content = requests.get(url).text

# Define the regular expression pattern to match links
pattern = re.compile(r'http[s]?://[^\s]+\.mp3')

# Find all matches in the HTML content
links = re.findall(pattern, html_content)

# Remove duplicates
links = list(set(links))

# Write the extracted links to a text file
with open('links.txt', 'w') as file:
    for link in links:
        file.write(link + '\n')
```

The issue is, the test link above contains not only .mp3's but also .flac, and .wav.

When I change the code (line 8) to the following to scrape and return all links containing those extensions above (.mp4, .flac, .wav), it outputs a text file with "mp3", "flac" and "wav". No links.

```
import re
import requests

url = input('Enter URL: ')
html_content = requests.get(url).text

# Define the regular expression pattern to match links
pattern = re.compile(r'http[s]?://[^\s]+\.(mp3|flac|wav)')

# Find all matches in the HTML content
links = re.findall(pattern, html_content)

# Remove duplicates
links = list(set(links))

# Write the extracted links to a text file
with open('links.txt', 'w') as file:
    for link in links:
        file.write(link + '\n')
```

I've been trying to understand where the error is. Regex, or something else? I can't figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: Format the code properly.

Comment: sorry, changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because in your second code, you capture (*with parenthesis)* only the extension of the url/file. So, one way to fix that, is to add another capturing group like below (*read comments*) :

```
import re
import requests

url = input('Enter URL: ')
html_content = requests.get(url).text

# Define the regular expression pattern to match links
pattern = re.compile(r'(http[s]?://[^\s]+\.(mp3|flac|wav))') # <- added outer parenthesis

# Find all matches in the HTML content
links = re.findall(pattern, html_content)

# Remove duplicates
links = list(set(links))

# Write the extracted links to a text file
with open('links.txt', 'w') as file:
    for link in links:
        file.write(link[0] + '\n') # <- link[0] instead of link[0]
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is to have non capturing groups with `?:`

```
pattern = re.compile(r'http[s]?://[^\s]+\.(?:mp3|flac|wav)')
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18425460/10231120).